# How to debug background/auto update?

Tags: automatic-updates

We have a very annoying problem with our [Unyson](http://unyson.io) plugin. For some users, all extensions are uninstalled automatically on random intervals ([#1](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson/issues/263), [#2](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-builder-extension-deactivating)) and we have no idea why this happens.
The only clue is that it can be caused by the WordPress automatic update.
We released [a fix](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson/blob/c5f034d55529ba42d84fe5932cccae3e0bb7198c/unyson.php#L153-L165) to stop automatic updates for Unyson plugin but the problem persists [#3](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/extensions-are-deactivating-every-2-days).

Why we think it's caused by the WP auto updates:

- Our extensions are located within plugin directory in `wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/extensions`
- Before plugin update, we move all extensions outside the plugin to a temporary directory
- After plugin update finished, we move them back in plugin directory (so the user doesn't have to install them again)
- We use [these 2 actions](https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson/blob/c5f034d55529ba42d84fe5932cccae3e0bb7198c/unyson.php#L104-L128) for before/after plugin update

I am thinking that on backgroup/auto update, the first action is fired, but the second one not (so the extensions are not moved back in plugin directory, so they are uninstalled).

We need a way to start manually WP backgroud/auto update and to debug the code execution (add `print_r()` or make requests to http://requestb.in/ with debug info).

Comment: Sorry this comment isn't constructive for the actual issue, but I do believe that storing those extensions inside a plugin folder that is distributed via wordpress.org just isn't a proper approach. Why aren't the extenstions separate plugins?

Comment: To be easier to manage. Extensions have a predefined directory structure and can be nested any level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WP installation must not require FTP credentials on plugins or extensions install.

1. Open `wp-content/plugins/unyson/unyson.php` and decrease the version

   Important: Decrease only the last digit (third).

   ```
   /**
    * ...
    * Version: 2.5.0
    * ...
    */
   ```
2. Add in {theme}/functions.php

   ```
   add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true', 99999 );
   ```
3. Open phpMyAdmin and delete `wp_option` named `cron`. You can run this SQL:

   ```
   DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'cron'
   ```
4. Open admin page (plugins page) and repeat:

   1. Refresh
   2. Wait 1 second until Unyson will auto-update.

If after 10 refresh nothing happens, run the steps 3. and 4. again.